# Android Visualizer class throwing runtime exception

Tags: android, audio, visualization

I am using AndroidFX Visualizer class in my demo app to read FFT but when i try to create object of that class its throwing Runtime exception (`java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -1`). Player class is my custom class for playback control and using same Player class i have implemented equalizer class and that's working fine. Do i need to add any permission in manifest file?

```
Player mediaPlayer = Player.GetInstance();
    mediaPlayer.LoadFile("song.mp3");
    mediaPlayer.Play();
    try{
    visual = new Visualizer(mediaPlayer.GetAudioSessionID()); // this line causing Exception 
    visual.setEnabled(true);
    visual.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Visual Ex", ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: must see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28427213/3496570

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That was due to my foolish mistake, that feature requires `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>` permission. thanks

Comment: Also, if using audio source 0 the same error gets thrown if you don't set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>` as [documented](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html).

Comment: Stack trace should have state that

Answer (score 13):

I know this is a very late answer but I also struggled with this problem and I want to share my experiences.

First, as the answer above mentioned, the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

and, if audio source 0 is used (`Visualizer(0); //system mix`),

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

are needed.  After adding the permissions to my app and installing the (new compiled) app again, my app still crashed. I found out, that the device has to be restarted, to use the Visualizer without any exception (for whatever reason). So if you develop an app and get this exception, **a restart could be required after adding the permissions to the app** .

Comment: I've been looking for an answer, and restarting my device fixed the issue! Thank you @Fruchtzwerg

Comment: Thank you Fruchtzwerg! It was restarting my device that fixed the issue as well. In NO WAY should this be required, and I believe it is a bug with android, specifically around the `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission.