# How to set audio equalizer in Android

Tags: android, audio

I am making a media player in which there is need to set equalizer effect using "seek bar" as "Bass","terrible","Rock","Pop","Medium". I got a link in which for doing this some NDK libraries used. Is there any Java library for doing it and please any explain what would be the logic for doing this.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.equalizertab);


      f
   }
  } else {
   try {
    ((GlobalState) getApplicationContext())
      .resetEQ();
   } catch (RemoteException re) {
    // TODO:
   }
  }
 }
});
```

Log cat out below:

```
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.apis.media/com.example.android.apis.media.AudioFxDemoActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -1
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1818)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1834)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1027)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -1
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer.<init>(Visualizer.java:182)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at com.example.android.apis.media.AudioFxDemoActivity.setupVisualizerFxAndUI(AudioFxDemoActivity.java:151)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at com.example.android.apis.media.AudioFxDemoActivity.onCreate(AudioFxDemoActivity.java:53)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
05-25 11:52:16.630: E/AndroidRuntime(19088):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1782)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can find equalizer in AudioFxDemo class.

And this is the link where you can find permissions to work out:

[Android Visualizer implementation crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595692/android-visualizer-implementation-crash)

Comment: hi abhi i am using AudiofxDemo.java class as in android developer site but its Force close , in raw folder i paste a song  in .wma extension ...LogCat are above as i edited my question pls refer to my quetion part for LogCat

Comment: Have you added the permission?

Comment: firstly i forgot to put..<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/> but after putting also  crashing occurs

Comment: Which version you are using...?and It is the worked sample for us...., check once everything

Comment: its working on my galaxy ace and galaxy y devices which is 2.3 v based but its not working on my Samsung galaxy tab v 3.2 ..why? i am really shocked here..

Comment: link is BROKEN!