# Android Custom Audio Equalizer

Tags: android, audio, equalizer

According to this topics :

[how to set Audio equalizer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738278/how-to-set-audio-equalizer-in-android) 
http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html

and

[Android Visualizer implementation crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595692/android-visualizer-implementation-crash)

I want to make a custom equalizer.
But i can't find any working examples. Actually i want to do equalizer animation on notification bar, when i pull down notification bar i want to see animated equalizer.

Is it possible?
What the start point for me? And is there any examples for audio equalizer.

### Goal :

[image]

Comment: hello have find the solution for this?

Comment: if you solve than please help me