# How to attach system Equalizer (Sound effect) with current media player (in my own music player app)..?

Tags: java, android

I have a media player. I want to apply system equalizer on it. I write this two-line code on current media player but system equalizer does not work on it. So finally i want to ask that how this going to work

```
Equalizer equalizer = new 
Equalizer(0,mediaplayer.getAudioSessionId());
equalizer.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Current media player means what? system player or you create own app ?

Comment: Sorry for not writing this...                                                                            
I create my own music player so I want to add system equalizer with it songs

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41242367/5110595)

Comment: I already applied this but not working. when i change equalizer like jazz, pop etc ..then no effect on media sound.