# Why i cant getFft

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, fft

I want to get FFT audio visualizer, can someone tell  how to do it?

class audioVisualizer:

```
import android.media.audiofx.Visualizer;

class AudioVisualizer extends Visualizer {

    public AudioVisualizer(int audioSession) {
        super(audioSession);
    }
}
```

so this is the code from the main activity

```
byte[] fft;
audioVisualizer = new AudioVisualizer(audioSessionId);

try {
    int a = audioVisualizer.getFft(fft);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

which causes

```
error:java.lang.IllegalStateException: getFft() called in wrong state: 1
```

(in short, I don't know how to receive FFT from visualizer, and I want to learn how to do it)
audioSessionId I get from my mediaPlayer

I hope you can help me :)

I googled how to get FFT but it didn't help

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: Have you read and followed all the instructions in [the `Visualizer` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer)? Do any of the answers to either of these questions help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6971567/3004881 https://stackoverflow.com/q/8595692/3004881

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order for the getfft method to earn, `audioVisualiser.setEnabled(true)` was required, but now there is a new problem `java_vm_ext.cc:570] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jarray was NULL` but this is a different question